# Using pip to install single class package without module.pyfile import

Tags: python, module, pip

I have a Python package with the following format, where `my_package.py` contains only a single class `myclass`:

```
$ .
|-- my_package/
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- my_package.py
|-- LICENSE.in
|-- README.rst
|-- setup.py
```

I upload this to pip and am able to install/import what I need with

```
> pip install my_package
python> from my_package.my_package import myclass
```

Is there a way of doing this so I don't have to call `my_package.my_package` and could just call

```
from my_package import myclass
```

I tried the following structure

```
$ .
|-- __init__.py
|-- my_package.py
|-- LICENSE.in
|-- README.rst
|-- setup.py
```

which I successfully uploaded / installed through pip but when I get the following error when importing

```
> import my_package
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named my_package
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move the `myclass` definition to `my_package/__init__.py`.

Comment: Is that standard or just a hack?

Comment: It's standard. Lots of 'real' libraries do it this way. That file exists for a reason. Put things in there that you want to import from multiple files in the same package to avoid circular dependencies, for example.

Comment: i've done this to avoid circular imports but didn't know about this, thanks!