# How to build a class into a Python module

Tags: python, python-module

I have a class file `fil1.py` and in this file, there is only one class called `f`. I want to build this class file into a module for which I've tried organizing my files like this:

```py
foo/
 foo/
    __init__.py
    file1.py # where class resides
 setup.py
 README.md
 LICENSE
```

In the `__init__.py`, I have one sentence:

```py
from file1 import f
```

Then, when I publish on pypi and then install back to my local computer. When I try:

```py
from foo import f
```

I got an error message:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'f' from 'foo'
```

I also tried

```py
import foo
foo.f
```

The error message was:

```
foo has no attribute f
```

I am not sure how to achieve what I want.

Comment: try this "from foo.file1 import f"

Comment: @python_user I tried and the error message is 'No module called file1'. And my ultimate goal is to direct import f from foo.

Comment: Does the original code work? I mean, the code before installing it from pypi.

Comment: @HuLuViCa Yes, it works well. Before installing, the ```file1``` will be the main code contains the class f. I can do ```from file1 import f```.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a "class file" in Python. A file is a module, and modules may contain zero or more classes, functions, or valid python statements not enclosed in a class or function (which run just one time when the module is imported). That said, I think you want:

foo/file1.py:

```
class f:
[...]
```

foo/__init__.py:

```
from foo.file1 import f
```

then all of the following are valid (assuming `foo` is available on `sys.path`, which includes the current working directory automatically as the first entry):

```
import foo
import foo.file1
from foo import f
from foo.file1 import f
```

`foo` is a package (because it contains `__init__.py`) with one module called `file1`. Alternatively, you could use a relative import inside `__init__.py`:

```
from .file1 import f
```

but that can get messy and is usually not appreciated in larger projects.

Comment: I agree. My first question is if there is a way that I can get around relative import? I want to make the import to an absolute import. The second question is how to make the import cleaner. As I only have one class need to import from ```file1.py```. How to make it possible to directly import this class?  Like ```import f```. Or ```from foo import f```

Comment: Any absolute import (ie. `import foo`) must be reachable using `sys.path`. See PEP328 for an explanation of absolute/relative imports (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/). It is standard to use `from foo.bar import baz, bat` inside of a package,there is nothing unclean or cumbersome about it at all. It was designed this way intentionally (again, PEP328).

Answer (score -1):

To achieve the absolute import from the package foo, I did is move my class definition into **py**.py. See [Using pip to install single class package without module.pyfile import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42767156/using-pip-to-install-single-class-package-without-module-pyfile-import).

```
root/
 foo/
    __init__.py # where class resides
 setup.py
 README.md
 LICENSE
```

Then I can do

```
from foo import f #f is the class previously in the file1.py
```

Comment: You can do `from foo import f`using the method I explained in my answer. The reason they both work is the same: the contents of `__init__.py` are implicitly used when you import the package, or `from` the package. In my answer, `from foo import f` works because a module called `f` is made available by code inside `__init__.py`. You have done basically the same thing, but using this approach of adding the class definition directly in `__init__.py` is almost always going to be frowned upon. This is bad practice. Don't do this.

Comment: I updated my answer to include the valid ways to do imports using this package/module structure. You might want to read this: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages